# Proof explanation: Division Algorithm

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-number-theory, proof-explanation

I have a quick question about this proof I wrote (not created by me) a while back.

> Let $a$ and $b$ be integers with $b > 0$. Then there exist two integers $q$ and $r$ such that $a = bq + r$ with $0 \leq r < b$.

[image]

> For the first case ($0\in S$), it states that $q=\frac{a}{b}=\frac{bk}{k}=b$ but then states that $a=bk=bk+0=bq+r$. Why suddenly $k=q$? Is this a typo? Should it be $a=qk+r$?

Comment: Yes it is a typo.  Let $q = \frac ab = \frac {bk}b = b$. And let $r = 0$.  Then $a = bk = bk + 0 = bq+r$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is a typo.  But the typo is that $q = \frac ab = \frac {bk}{b} = k$ so $q$ was supposed to be $k$ from the beginning.

$q = b$ is the error, and so, no, it should not be $a = bk + 0 = qk + 0=qk+r$.  That wouldn't get us anywhere toward proving $a = bq + r$ as the $k$ has nothing to do to do with the divisor $b$ which has suddenly disappeared.  In fact if $q= b$ then that would mean we are trying to prove $a = b^2$ which is ... not the case.

Answer (score 1):

Your question contains a typo.  It should be $q = \dfrac{a}{b} = \dfrac{bk}{\color{red}{b}} = \color{red}{k}$.